# C# download file using byte buffer will lead into strange behaviors

Tags: c#, .net, image, .net-core, download

when I'm trying to write a method that can report progress while download a file, and I wrote some codes:

```c#
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<(long current, long total)> Download()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            using var response = await client.GetAsync("<img-url>", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            await using var fileStream = new FileStream("<filepath>", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);

            var contentLength = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
            if (!contentLength.HasValue)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("cannot retrieve the content length of the request uri");
            }
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            long bytesRead, totalRead = 0L;
            var byteBuffer = new byte[1024];
            await using var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            while ((bytesRead = await contentStream.ReadAsync(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
            {
                await fileStream.WriteAsync(byteBuffer);
                totalRead += bytesRead;
                yield return (totalRead, contentLength.Value);
            }
        }
```

usage:

```c#
await foreach(var (current, total) in Download())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{current}/{total}")
}
```

but I found some problems after running this method, part of pixels of the image has wrong horizontal offset like
[this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDctG.png), and If I use the `HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync()` there will be no problems，and I tried several times, the offset dislocation all appear at the same location

Comment: I'm sure that image source is not the point, because I tried several different images and all of them are the same

Comment: What happens if a read from the content stream is less than 1024 bytes?

Comment: Problem solved, thanks